# Creating security for web application issue in the code for logging into the page

Tags: spring-boot, web, websecurity

I was building spring security web application using "https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/" but im getting error as " Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 20 11:47:42 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). "pls help!!

i tried to add some jsp dependencies / to use @ configuration but still same error and i am expecting the message to be displayed

Comment: You are getting this error that means your application is running. Now you need to set routing. How does your application to which JSP page it needs to go. Try setting some routing to `/`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: routing to be added near to java code or in the html code?